# could not be able to get data from list/array of firebase realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've been struggling to find solution to my issue that is I want to get data from this DB schema

```
{
      "brs" : {
        "route": [
          {
            "routeDestination": "DDDD1",
            "routeOrigin": "OOOO1",
            "bus" : {
                "busArrivalTime" : "created_at_timestamp",
                "busDepartureTime" : "created_at_timestamp",
                "busName" : "SOME NAME",
                "busSeatCost" : "0000",
                "busTotalSeats" : "000",
                "reservations": [
                  {
                    "reservationId": 1,
                    "reservationDate": "Wed Jul 06 23:54:56 EDT 2016",
                    "seats": [
                      {                
                        "seatNumber": 1
                      },
                      {               
                        "seatNumber": 2
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ] 
            }            
          },
          {
            "routeDestination": "DDDD2",
            "routeOrigin": "OOOO2",
            "bus" : {
                "busArrivalTime" : "created_at_timestamp",
                "busDepartureTime" : "created_at_timestamp",
                "busName" : "SOME NAME",
                "busSeatCost" : "0000",
                "busTotalSeats" : "000",
                "reservations": [
                  {
                    "reservationId": 1,
                    "reservationDate": "Wed Jul 06 23:54:56 EDT 2016",
                    "seats": [
                      {                
                        "seatNumber": 1
                      },
                      {               
                        "seatNumber": 2
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ] 
            }            
          },
          {
            "routeDestination": "DDDD3",
            "routeOrigin": "OOOO3",
            "bus" : {
                "busArrivalTime" : "created_at_timestamp",
                "busDepartureTime" : "created_at_timestamp",
                "busName" : "SOME NAME",
                "busSeatCost" : "0000",
                "busTotalSeats" : "000",
                "reservations": [
                  {
                    "reservationId": 1,
                    "reservationDate": "Wed Jul 06 23:54:56 EDT 2016",
                    "seats": [
                      {                
                        "seatNumber": 1
                      },
                      {               
                        "seatNumber": 2
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ] 
            }            
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

using this code

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View view) {
        FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = firebaseDatabase.getReference("route");            
        try {
            // Read from the database             
            myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {                      
                    GenericTypeIndicator<List<String>> t = new GenericTypeIndicator<List<String>> () {};
                    List<String> routes = dataSnapshot.getValue(t);                        
                    if( routes == null ) {
                        Snackbar.make(view, "Returned No Result" , Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .setAction("Action", null).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        Snackbar.make(view, "The routes Size is " + routes.size(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .setAction("Action", null).show();

                    }                       
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                    // Failed to read value
                    Log.w("BUS_TAG", "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
});
```

through the above code I only get the result Snack bar saying *Returned No Result*.

### UPDATE

I've tried as suggested by *@silverFoxA*, and made POJO simply

```
public class Route {

    private String routeDestination;
    private String routeOrigin;

    public String getRouteDestination() {
        return routeDestination;
    }

    public void setRouteDestination(String routeDestination) {
        this.routeDestination = routeDestination;
    }

    public String getRouteOrigin() {
        return routeOrigin;
    }

    public void setRouteOrigin(String routeOrigin) {
        this.routeOrigin = routeOrigin;
    }
}
```

and tried the code given in answer below

```
DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("routes");
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked ---- ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
final List<Route> routes = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Route>();
try {
    // Read from the database
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            System.out.println("The routes Size is " + dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());
            Snackbar.make(view, "The routes Size is " + routes.size(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
            for (DataSnapshot route : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                System.out.println("from " + route.child("routeOrigin").getValue() +
                        " to " + route.child("routeDestination").getValue());
            }            
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.w("BUS_TAG", "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }
    });
```

Now at this point I get result of ***The routes Size is 0***.

I've also tried in different way as

```
DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("brs");
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked ---- ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
final List<Route> routes = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Route>();

myRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        Route route = dataSnapshot.getValue(Route.class);
        routes.add(route);
        Snackbar.make(view, "The routes Size is " + routes.size(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

this code causing an exception that is

```
07-25 06:26:33.792 5861-5861/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.rhcloud.escot.bsr, PID: 5861
 com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.util.ArrayList to type com.rhcloud.escot.bsr.Route
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzalq.zzd(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzalq.zzb(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzalq.zza(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
     at com.rhcloud.escot.bsr.MainActivity$2$2.onChildAdded(MainActivity.java:94)
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzahh.zza(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajh.zzctc(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajk$1.run(Unknown Source)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
07-25 06:26:33.871 6417-6417/? E/SysUtils: ApplicationContext is null in ApplicationStatus
```

How can I get list/array of routes and iterate through it, I need some help in this case.

Comment: I would suggest using POJO

Comment: instead of accepting data snapshot object inside onDataChange you can use String and then parse the data or else accept custom data type of your choice to overcome delaying in parsing. let me try it and will update you shortly.

Comment: @VV any progress please?

Answer (score 1):

Try your last solution with this db:

```
DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().child("brs").child("route");

or

DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().child("brs/route");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very unlikely that you're actually storing an array in Firebase. It's much more likely that it's actually an associative array, where they keys may be integers.

When using the Firebase Database, it is a common practice to not use arrays and treat everything as a Map. In your case, this may solve your problems:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {                      
    System.out.println("The routes Size is " + snapshot.getNumChildren());
    for (DataSnapshot route: snapshot.getChildren()) {
        System.out.println("from "+route.child("routeOrigin").getValue()+
                           " to "+route.child("routeDestination").getValue());
    }
}
```

See `getChildrenCount()` and `getChildren()` in the [Android reference docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot#public-methods).

As silverFoxA commented, it is highly recommended that you create a Java class that represents the route. Dealing with `DataSnapshot` or (even worse) type-safe `List` or `Map` instances quickly drives even the most hardened developer insane.

Comment: Man! I'm still struggling with some issues, I've updated my question please have a look at that and give me a solution. As you've said ___"
It is very unlikely that you're actually storing an array in Firebase. It's much more likely that it's actually an associative array, where they keys may be integers. "___, would you suggest  me a different schema for this app? it'll be so kind of you!

Answer (score 0):

hey in your second updated change you are using a wrong key :

```
   DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("routes");

but in your json object its "route".
    ArrayList<Route> listRoutes = new ArrayList();
    DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("route");

    try {

        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot routeSnapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                Route route = routeSnapshot.getValue(Route.class);
                //save each route in arraylist
                listRoutes.add(route);


        }       
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
                Log.w("BUS_TAG", "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
            }
        });
```